# Unity Mysql fail to connect only Android

Tags: unity

I have issue that my android phone can't connect to the Mysql database. While on the editor or Windows build. Everything works fine, the game is able to connect. I get no erros when i build it, so i have no idea why it will not work on the Android phone. I have not tested on IPhone, since i have no Iphone to test on.

```
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   : PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   :   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor () [0x00000] in <2c8fc0407a5848dfa91f594842a803e7>:0
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   : Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   :   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor () [0x0001e] in <2c8fc0407a5848dfa91f594842a803e7>:0
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   : Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   :   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x0016c] in <2c8fc0407a5848dfa91f594842a803e7>:0
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   :   at DatabaseManager.CreateConnection () [0x00058] in <c2f1e2460e294aa39099177282cd5712>:0
04-11 16:00:31.482 18162 18206 E Unity   :   at GameManager.Start () [0x00017] in <c2f1e2460e294aa39099177282cd5712>:0
```

Comment: Have you tried logging any messages or status information when the game is running on Android, to track down the cause? What code do you currently use to read your database, and where does it fail on Android?

Comment: I've updated what i can see with adb log. I think it just fails on trying to connect with the database